# -System-Product-Name:~$ In Ubundu

Tags: linux

I Installed Ubuntu 14-04 LTS. I tried to  install software's using Terminal.Each time Software Installation successful but after installation  it always diSlays one command which is '-System-Product-Name:~$ '.I applied many this like my computer name etc.But not yet success.
I am new in Linux platform.Anyone aware  solution for the same  please help me.Thanks In advance

Comment: Are you talking about [the prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt)?!

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the following line to .bashrc file in your /home/your-username  folder

   ```
   export PS1="\[\e[0;32m\]\u@\h:\e[m\] \[\e[1;34m\]\w$\e[0m "
   ```
2. execute the command

   ```
   source .bashrc
   ```
3. Then read

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html

Answer (score 0):

`System-Product-Name` is the default hostname.

To change it, you can run `sudo nano /etc/hostname`, modify it with something like `yourname-desktop`